# Live username availability check in node express.js and client side js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am making an express, MongoDB, and handlebars(templating engine) web app with a form that lets users create their unique username. Now I want to display a little tooltip after set intervals to display whether the username is available or not. The way I have done it is by exposing an endpoint with JSON data about usernames

```
api.get("/usernames", (req, res)=>{
  users.find({}, (err, users)=>{
    let out = []
    users.forEach(user=>{
      out.push(user.uname)
    })
  })
  res.json({usernames: out})
})
```

And then I fetch the data and loop through the array on the client-side. But I don't think this method would scale very well. Is there an easier and more scalable way to achieve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
api.get("/usernames", (req, res)=>{
  users.find({}, (err, users)=>{
    let out = users.filter(x=>x.uname===req.body.name)
let result = out.length?"Already exists": "Available"
  })
res.json({result: result})
})
```